# How to construct object programmatically inside of JsonConverter WriteObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to create structure of nested objects on the flight inside of JsonConverter.WriteObject function.

#### Data structure:

```
Container 
    Object A 
    Object B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Can anyone recommend decent guide for writing Custom Converters?

```
var container = new JObject();

var fi = e.PropertyA;
JObject o = JObject.FromObject(fi);
o.AddFirst(new JProperty("type", new JValue(fi.GetType().Name)));

container.Add(o);
```

this approach failed with exception

> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

if I do

```
writer.WriteStartObject();
var fi = e.PropertyA;
JObject o = JObject.FromObject(fi);
o.AddFirst(new JProperty("type", new JValue(fi.GetType().Name)));

o.WriteTo(writer);
writer.WriteEndObject();
```

> 'Token StartObject in state ObjectStart would result in an invalid JSON object. Path 'sources[0]'.'

### Answer

Thanks to dbc I was able to make it trough with following code

```
            var container = new JObject();

            var fi = e.PropertyA;
            JObject o = JObject.FromObject(fi);
            o.AddFirst(new JProperty("type", new JValue(fi.GetType().Name)));

            container.Add(new JProperty("ObjectA", o));


            container.WriteTo(writer);
```

Comment: As I understand it, Newtonsoft has built in serializer and deserializer.  Why not build your object graph and then serialize it to a json object?  You are trying to reinvent something that is readily available to you.  Also, what you are attempting here will be much harder to read/maintain/update.  Good luck, but I recommend using the tools that are already available.

Comment: According to the [standard](http://www.json.org/) A JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs* so when writing an object you need to do [`WritePropertyName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WritePropertyName.htm) to before writing a property value.  Similarly when adding an object to an object you need to nest it in a [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) to specify the name.

Comment: user7396598 this is a part of much broader technical issue. you can read my other question on the entire topic in here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756595/custom-json-converter-for-a-collection-of-a-container-with-polymorphic-propertie

Comment: *Can anyone recommend decent guide for writing Custom Converters?* -- That's off-topic for stack overflow I think.

Comment: However, if you are looking to add a synthetic property `"type"` to all your objects, you might look at [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549680/3744182) which suggests using a custom contract resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) a JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs* so when writing an object you need to do [`WritePropertyName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WritePropertyName.htm) before writing a property value:

```
writer.WritePropertyName("PropertyA");
o.WriteTo(writer);
```

Similarly when adding a `JObject` to a `JObject` you need to nest it in a [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) to specify the name:

```
container.Add(new JProperty("PropertyA", o));
```

The exceptions you are getting reflect the fact that you are trying to add your `PropertyA` value to a JSON object without first specifying its name.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y1ZGVK) showing both.