# Add new property during serialization, remove property during deserialization

Tags: c#, attributes, json.net

Let's say I got a class like this:

```
[Version(123)]
public class Test
{

}
```

How would I add a property "Version": 123 to the generated json ?

I've been playin with a custom `ContractResolver` but with no success..

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        VersionAttribute attribute = (VersionAttribute)attributes.FirstOrDefault(att => att is VersionAttribute);
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            JsonProperty versionProperty = new JsonProperty();
            versionProperty.ValueProvider = new ValueProvider(attribute);
            versionProperty.PropertyType = typeof(int);
            versionProperty.PropertyName = "Version";
            versionProperty.DefaultValue = 0;
            properties.Add(versionProperty);
        }

        return properties;
    }
```

Comment: What prevents you from making the version a property of the class?  You have to modify the class anyway, so you might as well just make version a part of the class.

Comment: Seems very similar to [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549680/3744182).

Comment: Does the answer to [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549680/3744182) also answer your question or do you need more specific help?

Comment: @dbc this is sufficient ! thanks alo !