# How to virtually add Json attribute to an existing class [c#, system.text.json]

Tags: c#, system.text.json

How to "virtually" add Json attribute to an existing class?
*or more precisly*
**How is it posible to change the serialize behavior for a single property w/o creating a converter for the whole class and w/o rewriting/wrap the the whole class?**

If it would be my own class I would just apply one of the json attributes.
If this is not (yet) possible with system.text.json (.NET6) how is it with Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: With Json.NET you can add a synthetic property to an existing class or set of classes using a custom contract resolver.  See e.g. [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549680).  But System.Text.Json does not make its contract information public, see [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182), so you would need to create a DTO or converter, which you don't want to do.

Comment: You could make the converter generic -- i.e. basically maintain its own contract information.  I think [Dahomey.Json](https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json) does this e.g. when supporting data contract attributes.  But you would have to write this generic converter yourself, there's no extension point corresponding to `DefaultContractResolver` to inject modifications to object contracts.

Comment: @dbc thx. I feared it. Every time I start with system.text.json I get stuck with it. I am almost ready to write my own default JsonConverter. using reflection and supporting TypeDiscriptor, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel and actually I would expect something like this in the framework. I will research further...