# One-off Nested JSON Property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm interfacing with an API that has a request containing this snippet:

```
     "occurrence":{  
        "type":"XYZ"
     }
```

Instead of creating an `Occurence` object with a member `Type`, is there some Newtonsoft JSON magic that can serialize

```
  public string Occurence = "XYZ"
```

into the format above?

Comment: The field has little in common with the JSON representation. Why should a *field* become an object? Where would `type` come from?  You'd need to *transform* one form to the other. Whether you do that with JSON.NET objects or an anonymous type, eg `new {occurrence=new {type="XYZ"}}`, you still have to transform it.

Comment: This API has quite a few of these one-member objects, so I'm looking for a solution to minimize the number of classes.  JObject is one way but not really the safest option

Comment: use an anonymous type then. The two schemas have nothing in common. You *have* to transform one to the other one way or another.

Comment: Not in love with the anonymous type either.  Looks like maybe a custom JsonConverter is the way to do this

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818891/1695009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) to essentially flatten the JSON representation of the occurrence property into just the type.

```
class SomeModel
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(OccuranceConverter))]
  public string Occurence { get; set; }
}

class OccuranceConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
  public override string ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    var json = JObject.Load(reader);
    return json.GetValue("type").Value<string>();
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    var json = new JObject { ["type"] = value };
    json.WriteTo(writer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep this is essentially what I came up with as well.  Thanks!