# Transforming an array of name-value pairs in a JSON array with individual properties in the containing object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconvert

I'm trying to transform a JSON array to become object format.

Example:

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "date": "2019-6-30",
  "Speaker": [
    {
      "id": "name",
      "value": "Tiger"
    },
    {
      "id": "age",
      "value": "35"
    },
    {
      "id": "topic",
      "value": ".NET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert this to:

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "date": "2019-6-30",
  "name": "Tiger",
  "age": 35,
  "topic": ".NET"
}
```

I tried several ways, but had no luck. It seems I can't get the value of the internal array.  Please help.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: I tried follow example here : [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816736/json-net-custom-valueprovider-to-convert-objects-into-guid, but don't know how to deal with the array(speak fields list)

Comment: You can use a custom JsonConverter for your object: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm  During serialization (WriteJson method) you can convert your object from a flat list of properties to one containing an array, then serialize this object.  During deserialization (ReadJson) you can do the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to transform your JSON:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
JProperty arrayProp = root.Properties()
                          .Where(jp => jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
if (arrayProp != null)
{
    foreach (JObject item in arrayProp.Value.Children<JObject>())
    {
        root[(string)item["id"]] = item["value"];
    }
    arrayProp.Remove();
}

json = root.ToString();
```

This solution does not depend on the array property having any particular name, nor does it care what the item ids are.  However, if there are any ids in the array which overlap with an existing property in the root object, the value in the array will replace the one already in the root object.  Similarly, if there are any duplicate ids in the array, the last one will "win".

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3WkqN

Comment: Thanks Brain, I like this answer because it could deal with more dynamic speaker fields

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You only need a couple of classes to deserialise this JSON, for example:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    // Deserialise the array as a list of 'SpeakerItem'
    public List<SpeakerItem> Speaker { get; set; }

    // These will throw exceptions if the id doesn't match, but it's a start
    public string Name => Speaker.Single(s => s.Id == "name").Value;
    public string Age => Speaker.Single(s => s.Id == "age").Value;
    public string Topic => Speaker.Single(s => s.Id == "topic").Value;
}

public class SpeakerItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want concrete class, more like dynamic for this due to speaker attribute could change

Comment: This will handle different speaker attributes. Remove the 3 readonly properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this using JSON.Net, first of all your json is wrong (you have dot in the end of country line). I have used DynamoObjects.

```
string json = @"
            {
                ""country"": ""USA"",
   ""date"": ""2019-6-30"",
    ""Speaker"" : [
    {
        ""id"": ""name"",
        ""value"": ""Tiger""
    },
    { 
        ""id"": ""age"",
        ""value"": ""35""
    },
    { 
        ""id"": ""topic"",
        ""value"": "".NET""
    },
    ] 
}";
            dynamic animalJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            dynamic animal = new ExpandoObject();
            animal.country = animalJson.country;
            animal.date = animalJson.date;
            animal.name = animalJson.Speaker[0].value;
            animal.age = animalJson.Speaker[1].value;
            animal.topic = animalJson.Speaker[2].value;
            string modifiedAnimalJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(animal);
```

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. In this situation, there is no need to use it. The .NET DLR is very slow to use and removes any compile-time type safety.